# Php print out value from array only once

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

well my code is this one and i want if the locationname is the same to be printed only once

```
$arr1 =$erster[0][$id[0]]['location'];

foreach ($arr1 AS $ref_key => $location2):
print $location2['locationname'] ;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it:

```
$arr1 =$erster[0][$id[0]]['location'];

$repeats = array();
foreach ($arr1 AS $ref_key => $location2):
   $local_name = $location2['locationname'];

   if (!in_array($local_name,$repeats)){ // checking if $local_name is exists in "showed" array - $repeats
       print $local_name;                // if not - show $local_name             
       $repeats[] = $local_name;         // push  $local_name to "showed" array ( to $repeats)
   }

endforeach;
```

**EDIT** Another way . By comment @grebneke

```
$repeats = array();
foreach ($arr1 AS $ref_key => $location2):
$local_name = $location2['locationname'];

if (!array_key_exists($local_name,$repeats)){  // -//-
    print $local_name;                           
    $repeats[$local_name] = true;
}

endforeach;
```

Comment: Hi again voodoo417. You should really offer a code explanation sometimes! I understand this code, but author might not.

Comment: Inefficient `in_array()` if `$arr1` is large. Better put `$local_name` as array key and check if exists.

Comment: @crush Hi. Added as comments

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but still doesn't work. i think because this foreach belongs already to a foreach and still the array value is printed in all divs. when i print the arr1 i get back in first civ Array ( [] => Array ( [locationname] => Audimax ) ) Audimax and in second Array ( [265] => Array ( [locationname] => Audimax ) ) Audimax

Comment: You need iterate array of arrays. Show me `var_dump($erster[0][$id[0]]['location'])` and `var_dump($erster[0])` .

Answer (score 1):

You should instead make use of PHP built-in function `array_unique()`. Technically this function will only return the unique elements from the array.

```
$arr1 = $erster[0][$id[0]]['location'];
$newarray = array_unique($arr1);
print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I added an id and name field to my array and used

```
if($programm_location_id != $erster_programmpunkt[0][$id[0]]['location']['id']){
$programm_location_id = $erster_programmpunkt[0][$id[0]]['location']['id'];
$programm_location_name = $erster_programmpunkt[0][$id[0]]['location']['name'];
$programm_location_html = '<div class="span3">'.$programm_location_name.'</div>';

echo $programm_location_html;
}
```

thank you all